# Google maps var city map areas clickable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm generating  google map for a client. Im using the following code to generate an area on the map:

```
    citymap['Brandon'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.447862, 0.622404)
    };
```

I'm then using the following to style:

```
    for (var city in citymap) {
    var Options = {
    strokeColor: '#00AEEF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#00AEEF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: citymap[city].center,
    radius: 10000
  };
  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
  cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(Options);
}
```

I'm wondering if someone could advise as to how i can add a href to the area? I want to enable users to click through to a webpage. Im relatively new to this so any advice would be greatly received on this.

Comment: a jsFiddle would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Here's what I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/keithriches/b1wcgo2n/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could attach `click` event to `google.maps.Circle` object to open a link like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function (ev) {
        //window.location.href = "http://www1.nyc.gov/";
        window.open('http://www1.nyc.gov/','_blank');  //open link in a new window/tab
});
```

**Example**

```js
function initialize() {

    var citymap = {};
    citymap['NewYork'] = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712942, -74.002340), url: 'http://www1.nyc.gov/' };
    citymap['SanFrancisco'] = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.764486, -122.420434), url: 'http://sfgov.org/' };

    // Create the map.
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712942, -74.002340),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    for(var key in citymap){

        var city = citymap[key];
        var options = {
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.05,
            map: map,
            center: city.center,
            radius: 100000
        };


        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(options);

        (function(city) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(ev) {
                //window.location.href = city.url;
                window.open(city.url, '_blank'); //open link in a new window
            });
        })(city);

    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/vLuvq4eq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `click` function of `google.maps.Circle` as present in [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle)

> click   Arguments:  MouseEvent
>
> This event is fired when the DOM click event is fired on the circle.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am looking to have multiple circles on the map e.g:

        citymap['Thetford'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.415835, 0.751978)
        };
        citymap['Brandon'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.447862, 0.622404)
        };

As I'm new to all of this, would the click function be added to each area?

Comment: Yes, Of course. The answer of Vadim Gremyachev had solve your problem :). That's the accepted answer +1 ^^

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something here but I'm unable to see how this works? could anyone provide a jsfiddle with this working?

Comment: @KeithRiches: [Vadim Gremyachev's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/vLuvq4eq/3/) works fine :)

Comment: Ok I see the issue as to why i can't get this working and its a very simple reason, I had pop ups blocked within my browser. If i wish the page to load in itself (i.e. not in _blank)  can i assume i would just amend the line thus:

window.open(city.url);